# Count the number of unique elements in a vector by linear constraints (ILP)

Tags: optimization, integer-programming, constraints, discrete-optimization, mixed-integer-programming

Let $\mathbf{x}\in \{0,1\}^n$, be the objective variables of an ILP.
Further, let $\mathbf{a} \in \mathbb{N}_{\geq 0}^n$ be a ***given*** random vector and $\mathbf{w} = \mathbf{x} \odot \mathbf{a}$ where in the latter $\odot $ indicates an element-wise product.
We define the function $f(\mathbf{w})$ as the "number of unique elements" in $\mathbf{w}$ which are greater than zero. In fact, we choose the elements of $\mathbf{a}$ via $\mathbf{x}$.

For instance, suppose $\mathbf{a} = [2,4,2]$, then $f(\mathbf{w}) =1$ if  $\mathbf{x} = [1,0,1]$ and $f(\mathbf{w}) = 2$ if $\mathbf{x} = [0,1,1]$.

The objective function of an ILP is a minimization of a function composed of $\mathbf{x}$ and $f(\mathbf{w})$.

Now, the question is, is it possible to find $f(\mathbf{w})$ by linear constraints?

One approach would be to define $2^n$ objective variables, instead of $n$,  and map them to one of the $2^n$ possible values of $f(\mathbf{w})$ but that will explode the number of variables.

Comment: I have updated your question so it uses the first letters of the alphabet for parameters and the last letters for variables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $E$ denote the set of unique elements in $a$, and let $y_e$ ($e \in E$) be a binary variable that takes the value 1 if the value $e$ is selected. The objective term is $f(w) = \sum_e y_e$, and the constraints are $y_e \geq x_i$ for all $(e,i)$ for which $a_i = e$.

Comment: Thanks but I did not completely get your approach. For $\mathbf{a}$ given in the question, based on your definition, $E = 2$ (we have two unique elements). Right? Then, what does $e \in E$ mean? $e = 1,2$? and, $a_i =e$ may not hold for any $a_i$. I got confused. Could you please explain in more details?

Comment: @Mahdi $E$ are the unique elements of $a$ (so $E=\{2,4\}$), so $a_i=e$ holds for at least one $i$. I have clarified this in my answer.

Comment: Great! Now it is clear. Many thanks.